# Firebase security rules - writing from Firebase functions

Tags: firebase, paypal, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to implement proper Firebase security rules and ran into one challenging issue. I've got public listings which should be viewable by all, can't be deleted or edited by anyone except by the author of the listing. When someone buys (via PayPal plugin) a given listing, I need to write to this listing changing it's status to SOLD. Essentially this is like a third party (not the listing author) has to write to a given listing.

Here are the rules I have so far:

```
"listings": {
    ".read": "auth.provider === 'facebook'",
    "$listingID": {
          ".write": "auth.provider === 'facebook' && ((!data.exists() && newData.exists()) || root.child('listings/'+$listingID+'/UID').val() === auth.uid)"
    }
}
```

I have a feeling that I need to write to Firebase from my backend (Firebase functions), but I'm not sure how the security rules will work out, as it would still be the buyer (3rd party) upon whose request we'd need to write the new status SOLD to the listing node which is only editable by the author.

Any advice/recommendations on how to go about this situation will be highly appreciated!

Many thanks!